# Why do I need to double click a cell for the latest value of my excel document (build in) property?

Tags: excel, properties

I have an excel document with some macros. These macros are getting my "build in", "custom" and "SharePoint content type"  properties. I am executing these macro functions in 3 cells.

Here are my 3 macro functions:

[image]

The problem is that when these properties are changed, I only see the old value. When I would like to see the new value in a cel, I need to double click on the cell, press on enter, and after this you see the new value of the property.

See here an example.

This is the first value of the title property:

[image]

After this I have changed the title from "This is my title old" to "This is my title new". After this change you still see the old value in the cell:

[image]

Now I am going to force the latest version of this property by double clicking the cell (B2), press on the enter key. And Voila, there is the latest value of my title document property.

[image]

What can I do to avoid these manual forcing the latest version of a document property? I would like to show always the latest version of the document property.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Volatility.

Because you are not changing prop in the worksheet, Excel does not know it should re-calculate the UDFs  For example:

```
Public Function WhatTimeIsIt() As Date
    WhatTimeIsIt = Now
End Function
```

will calculate only once, but:

```
Public Function WhatTimeIsIt() As Date
    Application.Volatile
    WhatTimeIsIt = Now
End Function
```

will recalculate whenever the worksheet is re-calculated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast answer. I have changed the function like you said, but the value is not automatic changed after I change the document property. Here is my currenct function: Public Function GetMyBuiltinDocumentProperties(prop As String) As String
    Application.Volatile
    GetMyBuiltinDocumentProperties = ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties(prop)
End Function

Comment: Make no mistake!  It still is not going to be automatic.  You still must re-calculate the worksheet, but at least you can avoid the double-clicking....Sadly, changing Properties is not a "trap-able" event.

Comment: I see that when you close the excel document, and reopen it, then you will see the latest value. Is there also another real time solution?